# Map an Object Literal to Another Object Literal Using Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, functional-programming, typescript-typings

Is it possible to have a Lodash style "mapValues" and "mapKeys" functions, that returns a mapped object literal - instead of a (too) generic record type?

What I mean:

```
_.mapValues({a:1, b:2}, (v) => v === 1 ? 'aaa' : 'bbb')
```

This code (Lodash library), returns a `Record<'a' | 'b', 'aaa' | 'bbb'>`, instead of the literal type `{a: 'aaa', b: 'bbb'}`

Same as Ramda/Fp-ts functions - some type information is lost.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that in a simple `const a = 1, b = a + 1;`  the variable `b` wouldn't get the literal type `2` either, it's just a `number`. There is no constant propagation, and no computations are applied to literal types.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think the TypeScript compiler has enough support for higher order type analysis to do this for you.  The problems I see:

- There's no good way for the compiler to infer that the function `const mapper = (v: 1 | 2) => v === 1 ? "aaa" : "bbb"` is of a conditional generic type like `<V extends 1 | 2>(v: V) => V extends 1 ? "aaa" : "bbb"` or of an overloaded function type like `{(v: 1): "aaa", (v: 2): "bbb"}`. If you want the compiler to treat the function like that you will have to assert or annotate the type manually.
- Even if it *could* infer that, there's no way to write a type function like `Apply<typeof f, typeof x>` where `f` is an overloaded or generic function of one argument, and `x` is an acceptable argument for it so that `Apply<typeof f, typeof x>` is the type of `f(x)`.  Shorter: [there's no `typeof f(x)` in TypeScript](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6606).  So while you can *call* `mapper(1)` and the compiler knows the result is of type `"aaa"`, you can't represent that knowledge in the type system.  That prevents you from doing something like [overloaded function resolution](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29732) or [generic function resolution](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14400) in the type system.

---

The most straightforward typing I can imagine for `_.mapValues` would give you the wide `Record`-like type, and you'd have to [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) a narrower type if you want that:

```
declare namespace _ {
  export function mapValues<T, U>(
    obj: T,
    fn: (x: T[keyof T]) => U
  ): Record<keyof T, U>;
}
const obj = { a: 1, b: 2 } as const;
type ExpectedRet = { a: "aaa"; b: "bbb" };
_.mapValues(obj, v => (v === 1 ? "aaa" : "bbb")); // Record<"a"|"b", "aaa"|"bbb">
const ret = _.mapValues(obj, v => (v === 1 ? "aaa" : "bbb")) as ExpectedRet;
```

---

Otherwise you have to jump through many flaming hoops (manually specifying types, manually declaring functions as overloads) and you end up with something not much safer than a type assertion and a lot more complicated:

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any
  ? (k: U) => void
  : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void)
  ? I
  : never;

declare namespace _ {
  export function mapValues<T, U extends Record<keyof T, unknown>>(
    obj: T,
    fn: UnionToIntersection<{ [K in keyof T]: (x: T[K]) => U[K] }[keyof T]>
  ): U;
}

function mapper(v: 1): "aaa";
function mapper(v: 2): "bbb";
function mapper(v: 1 | 2): "aaa" | "bbb" {
  return v === 1 ? "aaa" : "bbb";
}

const obj = { a: 1, b: 2 } as const;
type ExpectedRet = { a: "aaa"; b: "bbb" };
const ret = _.mapValues<typeof obj, ExpectedRet>(obj, mapper);
```

Not sure if that's even worth explaining... you have to manually specify the input and expected output types in the call to `_.mapValues` because there's no way the compiler can infer the output type (as mentioned above).  You have to manually specify that `mapper` is an overloaded function.  The typing for `_.mapValues` is complicated and uses [`UnionToIntersection`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type) to describe the required overloaded function as the intersection of function types taking input values to output values.

So, I'd stay away from this and just use a type assertion.

---

Hope that helps; sorry I don't have a more satisfying answer.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAlC8D2AnAJgGQEsBrZAbwFgAoJJHdAGxC2VElgWQH0kLqakIADxjYALkgBmAV2DxRBDMCRgQMAGoh6U6AB4AKgBokAVQB8ACir9+GAEYArAFxJDV65ODPzg53oDaJACeGBIuALoAlEgAvKYmbjQRzmiYuDpBIS5GZgDcbgC+bpjAUOJ29jE8SCDOAIxGts4ATEj51VBIxaV5fKKBMMgAosLoohA4aOLRVTVIAEQgi3M5SI3zthtzrT00nAB0Kuqa2lDm5UYAbjFx5lfR90i1SAD884sgW85zG7ZzERErAD0gNQ6GwOB0CzmAB9vnMjAslrCfnNTEVFKUkMwpkh9ocNFpoGcHJdrkhbjEHk9XoiPkgvij-u0kMMBnJxpMeoVKFRWNA4IgkABlURYRQAc3ogT0-XGACEpKIAIIAd2k9B4bj6AxMwAUwD0GAAksAxlgoKN9TozJVzMYBIIxsAcB0QMBAgkXuSiM5jFFYkgLhgCDhPc5gBALhAsFEhE6XeTzD6kARgBJo0gjf64kGQxFPa8jWGkBGo1gem46PBGMwS+B+RxcZq+DQhCIsOJpLJ5IplKoCSd9NkHfGOilwekIMFQoYkDIiMAMCrgKYLJ6aOVfAZ1x5fXrFIaTWaLXIraQkH4ANIppQZGdhLw+FxXyJk4wv1oBKeZPRhNEtpAkhMHZWioNwu1PXtDgGLBbjqIDaWWcCZEgpRoOjOCkCaBCURAiCezQ1QYMwp5oSwhD3i2Mjvk2ZtrGxKQsCUO4qS9RD6XWTYQO5dESjKBxKnPWZ6lWZpWmZLpRBA7UhhGdkJggHEhK+SiVjWGjfm2XjMWxSo8X7Y5dBkzJzhZOSxgU0QLFM9CYy5KggA)

Answer (score 0):

I know I've seen it somewhere. But I think you wanted this.

```js
const mapped = Object.assign({}, ...Object.keys(ori).map((key) => {return {[key]: /*...*/}}))
```

Example:

JS:

```js
const x = {a: 1, b: 2};
const y = Object.assign({}, ...Object.keys(x).map((key) => ({[key]: x[key] + 1})));

// y = {a: 2, b: 3}
```

TS:

```js
const x: Record<string, number> = {a: 1, b: 2};
const y = Object.assign({}, ...Object.keys(x).map((key) => ({[key]: x[key] + 1})));
```

Comment: Thanks - but does not compile under TypeScript 3.5

Comment: Although now it compiles - "x" is a Record instead of object literal, and "y" has the type "any". Not what I was looking for. Thanks again.

Comment: @Daniel I'm pretty sure you need to type everything in TS because everything needs to be predictable. If you want an `any` type, just use `Record<string, any>` for `x`, but most linters would discourage using `any` as a type, as this conflicts with TS's philosophy. And assigning type `Record<string, number>` to y would still compile, because I personally use this in my projects.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for the opposite of what you suggest (any type).